# What should I call my about me page

Tags: seo

Many Search Engines says that "about" is a stop word, but if I want create an "about me" page how would this make the website's SEO worse? If it makes it worse, how could I improve or change the name: "about me"?

Comment: Show me where a search engine has called "about" a stop word? Also, show me any example of using that word being harmful in any way for SEO. "About me" is a perfectly fine name for that page.

Comment: You're also confusing stop words and when they may even be used with something that has no relevance or connection to them. The name of your page should be relevant to what it is about - regardless of what words it includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Conde and zigojacko are right. Lose the idea of *stop words should be avoided*. That was never really the case and is especially true these days because of semantic searches.

The About page is a staple that is looked for especially by Google and Bing in building domain trust. About, About Us, and Contact pages are evaluated slightly differently in that the domain registration data is compared to these pages as well as page footers for consistency. If a sites registration information matches information found on the website, the closer the match the better the metric score will be. It is one of many, but an important one. So for this reason, an About or About Us page becomes important. It must be identifiable in the traditional sense to have value. Otherwise it will not be found and will not advantage your sites trust score at all. That is part 1 of the answer.

On a side note: SEO is not complicated. There are too many VooDoo priestess and conjurers of SEO magic out there spouting extremely silly stuff. One parrots the advice of seudo and sometimes real leaders and then you get hundreds if not thousands of *me too* articles confusing poor folks who have trouble seeing through the fog. It is okay to be confused as to which way to go in the fog, just don't buy the bull in the process. Fog fine, bull bad.

Having said that, create sites and pages for people and not machines. Do not worry about silly little detail stuff. Create pages, links, and tags for humans first. Yes keywords are important, but you will be surprised by what works today! Google is looking for semantic titles, descriptions, header tags, and so forth and will reward sites that appear to take this approach. And that ties into the About page. Make it for humans. Get personal if it is a personal site. That is fine. But make it for humans. And that is part 2 of the answer!